# get Error On Creating a New Certificate Database

Tags: firefox-addon, certificate

i'm trying to creating a new certificate database with `CertUtil`. like with this command:

```
C:\Users\mahdi>certutil -N -d .\
```

but i get error :

```
C:\Users\mahdi>certutil -N -d .\
CertUtil: Unknown arg: -N
CertUtil -?              -- Display a verb list (command list)
CertUtil -dump -?        -- Display help text for the "dump" verb
CertUtil -v -?           -- Display all help text for all verbs
```

and no any link and website help me to resolve this problem. i want to create new database for SIGN firefox addons

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?

Comment: @Noitidart i can not make